# Kotlin : string to array to key value

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, hashmap

I'm trying to create a key => value Hashmap.

First, I have a string delimited by **`<br />`**. Then, I split it with **split()** (to get each string independently).

Then, I need to split each result with **"="**. The first part will be the key (I need it to be a string) and the second one will be the value (an int)

For now I have

```
val formules = objInput.getString(Constants.formules)
val hashmap = HashMap<String, Int>()
val resSplit = formules.split("<br />")
    resSplit.forEach {
      val splitFormule = it.split(" = ")
      val key = splitFormule.elementAt(0)
      val value = splitFormule.elementAt(1)
      Log.i(TAG, "$key")
}
```

I have this error when I'm trying to display the value :

> Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: At some point of time `splitFormule` contains only one element. Check it.

Comment: what did you expect? you may want to debug it and you will see the problem... could it be that your string doesn't contain any ` = `?

Comment: Yes @Rolan, it was that. It forgot to add this condition. Thanks, I feel kind of stupid ^^'

Answer (score 3):

Be careful that your input is correct. Whitespaces are relevant. `<br />` is different 
 from `<br/>` and `=` is different from `<space>=<space>`. Assuming your input looks like this:

```
foo = 3<br />bar = 5<br />baz = 9000
```

Then you can create a map using this simple expression:

```
val map = formules
    .splitToSequence ("<br />") // returns sequence of strings: [foo = 3, bar = 5, baz = 9000]
    .map { it.split(" = ") } // returns list of lists: [[foo, 3 ], [bar, 5 ], [baz, 9000]]
    .map { it[0] to it[1] } // return list of pairs: [(foo, 3), (bar, 5), (baz, 9000)]
    .toMap() // creates a map from your pairs
```

Comment: you may want to use `splitToSequence` instead of `split` otherwise you create a new list on each `map`-call, which you basically discard all when you call `toMap`...

Comment: Thank you very much @Roland! I was not aware of that. Made me read this interesting article about collections vs. sequences: https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/effective-kotlin-use-sequence-for-bigger-collections-with-more-than-one-processing-step-649a15bb4bf

Answer (score 1):

As you already said, you forgot a condition to check whether your string even contains a `=`.

Some furter notes: you can replace your [`elementAt`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/element-at.html) also with [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/get.html) or with the [indexing operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed) (e.g. `splitFormule[0]`).

You may also be interested in [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html), e.g. your split could also be written as follows:

```
val (key, value) = it.split(" = ") // no need to extract the values from the array, if you know how the splitted data looks like
// you may even want to use the following if there could potentially be more than 1 '=' in the value part
val (key, value) = it.split(" = ", limit = 2) // at most 2 parts
```

Finally another variant, which skips keys if there aren't any values associated to them:

```
val yourMap = formules.splitToSequence("<br />")
    .filter { it.contains("=") }
    .map { it.split("""\s*=\s*""".toRegex(), limit = 2) }
    .map { (key, value) -> key to value } // destructuring
    .toMap()

// or: instead of filtering do a takeif and if you require those keys, do something appropriate there (e.g. set a default value instead)
val yourMap = formules.splitToSequence("<br />")
    .map { it.split("""\s*=\s*""".toRegex(), limit = 2) }
    .mapNotNull { it.takeIf { it.size == 2 } } // this discards now the entries without any value
    .map { (key, value) -> key to value } // destructuring
    .toMap()
```